# Unable to use GPU after Tensorflow installation in Thinkpad E470

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am a beginner with TensorFlow. My computer is Thinkpad E 470. The display of my computer is Inter HD Graphics 620 and the render of my computer is NVIDIA GeForce 940 MX, which should support TensorFlow (GPU version).

However, after the installation of TensorFlow. When I try to run the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"   # see issue #152
#os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1,2,3,4,5"
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

The feedback is:

```
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 8429792091945466266
]
```

Here is another code and its result:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
print (sess.run(c))

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation 'MatMul_1': 
Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:1 but available devices 
are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device 
specification refers to a valid device.
 [[Node: MatMul_1 = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, 
_device="/device:GPU:1"](a_1, b_1)]]
```

Where is my GPU? Thanks!

Comment: 1) How did you install tensorflow? (exact command) 2) Which version of CUDA do you have? 3) Which version of cuDNN do you have?

Comment: Also, what operating system are you using? On windows this may work well, but on linux, you may need to start your python with `optirun python`

Comment: Have you tried `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):` instead of `with tf.device('/gpu:1'):`? Also, I'd try setting the `allow_growth` config option to `False`.

Comment: @MatthewScarpino I try this command. But the result is still the same. Thanks.

Comment: @gunan I use Windows system. Thanks!

Comment: @GPhilo 1.conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6; 2. activate tensorflow; 3. pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu. Successfully installed bleach-1.5.0 enum34-1.1.6 html5lib-0.9999999 markdown-2.6.9 numpy-1.13.3 protobuf-3.5.0 setuptools-37.0.0 six-1.11.0 tensorflow-gpu-1.4.0 tensorflow-tensorboard-0.4.0rc3 werkzeug-0.12.2 wheel-0.30.0 Thanks.

Comment: @GPhilo I do not know how to get the version of CUDA and cuNN. Can you tell me how? Thanks.

Comment: @GPhilo It looks like tensorflow in my computer uses the display (Inter HD Graphics 620) instead of the render (NVIDIA GeForce 940 MX).

Comment: You need CUDA 8 to be able to use TF. Make sure it is installed (I have a feeling it isn't)

Comment: @GPhilo Thanks a lot. I am trying to install it. But it seems to let me upgrade my windows 10 system first.

Comment: @Yipin These links look relevant for windows dual GPU setups: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025951/unable-to-install-cuda-8-0-properly-in-optimus-windows-10-laptop/  http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/optimus-developer-guide/index.html#control-panel-settings-and-driver-updates-with-optimus

Comment: @gunan Thank you! gunan. I have installed it. That is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

On dual-GPU systems you need to make sure your discrete GPU is activated before or while running tensorflow.
On linux, you need to install `bumblebee` and prefix your commands with `optirun`.
On windows, I have not used myself but this guide looks relevant:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025951/unable-to-install-cuda-8-0-properly-in-optimus-windows-10-laptop/